# Trigger a function only once inside a continously triggered function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which is triggered on every mouse-down event when the mouse pointer is over the image.
Now, I call two functions in this mouse-down function.

I need one function `Triangulate()` be called every time and the other one `ImageCalculation()` last time only.

Here last time only means, a gap of minimum 3 seconds or more should be there between consecutive `img_mouse_down()` function calls.

Below is my code:

```
function img_mouse_down(){
  if(leftMouseButton){
    Triangulate(); //Call this function every time.
    ImageCalculation(); //Call this function only the last time
  }
}
```

If I click over the image 5 times continuously and then pauses for 3 or more seconds, `Triangulate()` should be called 5 times and the `ImageCalculation()` should be called only once.

How to achieve this?

Comment: can ImageCalculation() be called after the 3 seconds pause?

Comment: FYI, this is called *event debouncing*.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: Yeah. Got the solution. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should address your problem. The timeout is cleared on every call and otherwise ImageCalculation is triggered after 3 seconds.

```
var timer = null
function img_mouse_down () {
    if(leftMouseButton){
    Triangulate();
    if (timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        ImageCalculation()
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Coxer for your reply. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var glob_timeout_holder;
function img_mouse_down(){
  if(leftMouseButton){
    Triangulate(); //Call this function every time.

    clearTimeout(glob_timeout_holder); //clear if any previous continuing timeouts

    glob_timeout_holder = setTimeout(ImageCalculationlast, 3000);
  }
}
```

This may help you, as far as I understood. Everytime img_mouse_down() run, it will set a timeout to execute ImageCalculation(), but just before that kill any previous timeOuts, result is, if user stop clicking, ImageCalculation() will be called once 3 seconds after last click.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kemal Dağ. But somehow, ImageCalculationlast() was called every time. Coxer's answer worked for me. Idea was same, but he initialized with null and checks for not null before clearing.